Estimating Heat transfering by measuring
Consider the setup with closed chamber with two flat metal objects with know dimensions.
The first object can be heated or cooled by peltier module and the second one is placed on top of the first one.
For testing,  both object have temperature sensors for logging temp change, but for final setup, only bottom (first) object will have sensor and temp measurement.
My questions:

how to estimate heat transfer function between two object by measured temps of the two objects
once the heat transfer function is estimated, how to apply this heat transfer model on estimation of temperature of the second object, by using only temperature measurements of the first object?

Is this even possible?
Sorry if I didn't explain this more in detail, since I'm not very familiar with thermodynamics.

If you know the mass of the bottom disk and the specific heat capacity of your disk, the calculation is trivial For an amount of heat transfer $\Delta Q$, a temperature change $\Delta T$, a mass $m$ and a specific heat capacity $c$, $\Delta Q=mc\Delta T$.
If you need high accuracy, or large temperature ranges, you may have to worry about the fact that $c$ does depend on temperature, so the above equation is imperfect (the more exact notation is a calculus equation, $\frac{dQ}{dT}=mc$).  There are tabulated versions of this which account for this effect, such as this graph from Wikipedia for water:

You cannot calculate the temperature of the second object without some way to measure heat capacity.  One way you could approach it is to take multiple measurements as the heat transfers and the temperatures change.  However, this gets into a much more complicated situation.  At these intermediate times, the system is not in equilibrium, which means the temperature may not be the same across the disk.  It could be higher on one side and lower on the other.  This quickly becomes a different problem than the one you describe.
